# How can I insert the developer ID from maven's pom.xml into a another file using resource filters?

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have filled out the `<developers>` section in my `pom.xml` to include the developer ID. I need to have maven copy it to another file every build. Normally I do this using resource filters. However, `developers.developer.id` or `developers.id` is not printing anything. `developers` does print `[org.apache.maven.model.Developer@7026b7ee]` so I know it's in the maven context but how do I get the actual field value?

Here is the tag in my `pom.xml`:

```
<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>a00000</id>
    </developer>
</developers>
```